# Get index of where group starts and ends pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, indexing, grouping

I grouped my data by month. Now I need to know at which observation/index my group starts and ends. 
What I have is the following output where the second column represents the number of observation in each month:

```
date
01       145
02      2232
03     12785
04     16720
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

with this code:

```
leave.groupby([leave['date'].dt.strftime('%m')])['date'].count()
```

What I want though is an index range I could access later. Somehow like that (the format doesn't really matter and I don't mind if it returns a list or a data frame)

```
date
01       0 - 145
02      146 - 2378
03     2378 - 15163
04     15164 - 31884
```

Comment: you want the minimum and maximum index for each group?

Comment: yes exactly, (so that I can access it later for indexing in a loop)

Comment: OK I think I understand

Comment: This question would benefit from a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1):

try the following - using `shift`

```
df['data'] = df['data'].shift(1).add(1).fillna(0).apply(int).apply(str) + ' - ' + df['data'].apply(str)
```

OUTPUT:

```
     data
date    
1    0 - 145
2    146 - 2232
3    2233 - 12785
4    12786 - 16720
5    16721 - 30386
6    30387 - 120157
```

Comment: You forget add `1`

Comment: like `df['data'].shift(1).fillna(0).add(1).apply(int).apply(str)`

Comment: You can avoid the `int` to `str` using string formatting and use `.cat` instead of `+` - eg: `df.date.shift(1).fillna(0).add(1).apply('{:.0f}'.format).str.cat(df.date.astype(str), sep=' - ')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a data frame containing the indices of first and last occurrences of each value.

How about something like this.

Example data (note -- it's better to include reproducible data in your question so I don't have to guess):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
n = 500
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'date':pd.to_datetime(
                  pd.DataFrame( { 'year':  np.random.choice(range(2017,2019), size=n),
                                  'month': np.random.choice(range(1,13),      size=n),
                                  'day':   np.random.choice(range(1,28),      size=n)
                                 } )
         ) }  
    )
```

Approach:

```
pd.DataFrame( ( { '_month_':x,'firstIndex':y[0],'lastIndex':y[-1]} 
                for x, y in df.index.groupby(df['date'].dt.month).items() 
               )
             )
```

Result:

```
    _month_  firstIndex  lastIndex
0         1           0        495
1         2          21        499
2         3           1        488
3         4           5        498
4         5          14        492
5         6          12        470
6         7          15        489
7         8           2        494
8         9          18        475
9        10           3        491
10       11          10        473
11       12           7        497
```

If you are only going use it for indexing in a loop, you wouldn't have to wrap it in `pd.DataFrame()` -- you could just leave it as a generator.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. But unfortunately it doesn't work. I am working with dates, so my column I group by is a date column. I get the following error: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

`leave.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)


pd.DataFrame( ( { 'group':x,'firstIndex':y[0],'lastIndex':y[-1]} 
                for x, y in leave.index.groupby([leave['date'].dt.strftime('%m')])['date'].items() 
               )
             )`

Comment: @LN_P instead of `.groupby([leave['date'].dt.strftime('%m')])['date'].items()`, try `.groupby([leave['date'].dt.month.items()`.  No need to use `strftime` and not sure what you're doing with the `date` column there.  I will update my answer.